# How i can solve TypeError: can't access property 0, _vm.allCounts.teachersCount is undefined

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

In my vue file i have difined axio as follows,

```
getCounts(){
   axios.get('api/get-count').then(response => {
   this.allCounts = response.data.more;
   console.log(this.allCounts)
   });
},
```

after running printed console.log as follows image,
[image: after printing consol.log]

I access this data,

```
{{allCounts.teachersCount[0] ? allCounts.teachersCount[0] : "-"}}
{{allCounts.studentsCount[0] ? allCounts.studentsCount[0] : "-"}}
{{allCounts.subjectsCount[0] ? allCounts.subjectsCount[0] : "-"}}
```

without any issue that values are printed in my web page, but if i look the my console it shows some errors as follows,

[image: errors in console]

Data are show without any issue but this error show in console, how i can solve that?

Comment: Might something else modify the this.allCounts(). As however you would expect in chrome console.log() to show the state on the line you place the log line.

Unfortunatly that isn't wat it does. If you manipulate our object somewhere outside that method, and click the + collapse on your chrome dev console. it's going what it is, at the moment you click it....

Comment: How do you have allCounts defined? in data? Computed prop? Can you share its definition please :)

Comment: return{ allCounts:[] } this way i defined allCounts array

Comment: I edited my return method like return{ allCounts: { studentsCount: [], subjectsCount: [], teachersCount: [], },} after applying this changes problem was solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely issue here, is that before your response is returned your template is trying to access the undefined indexes of allCounts.

Where you are initializing the allCounts you should put:

If in data for example:

```
    data() {
        return {
            ...
            allCounts: {
                studentsCount: ['-'],
                subjectsCount: ['-'],
                teachersCount: ['-'],
            },
            ...
        };
    },
```

If you define it like this, then before you have your response your template will not have errors.

To avoid making your vue code as explicitly aware of the structure of the response from your backend you could have computed properties like:

```
    computed: {
    ...
        studentsCount(field) {
            if (this.allCounts.studentCount) {
                return this.allCounts.studentCount[0];
            }

            return '-';
        },

        teachersCount(field) {
            if (this.allCounts.teachersCount) {
                return this.allCounts.teachersCount[0];
            }

            return '-';
        },

        subjectsCount(field) {
            if (this.allCounts.subjectsCount) {
                return this.allCounts.subjectsCount[0];
            }

            return '-';
        },
    ...
    }
```

And reference them in the template like:

```
{{ studentsCount }}
{{ subjectsCount }}
{{ teachersCount }}
```

This way, if your response changes you wont have to update the template and the data, but can instead just update the computed properties.

Comment: return{ allCounts: { studentsCount: [], subjectsCount: [], teachersCount: [], },}  IT solves after applying this one

Comment: i have a question like this one ,how can i define this one in return method like this question answer that you provided "profitDetails[1].total"

Comment: it was not solve the problem i have to access {{profitDetails[0].total}}  {{profitDetails[1].total}}  {{profitDetails[2].total}}  {{profitDetails[3].total}} .So i have to define it in return method how it can possible

Comment: @ShasikaMadhushan You need to make a new question, to cover that topic. This solution was for your specific problem, and computed properties wont help you with what you are asking for either.